# Get remote IP in Parse.com

Tags: node.js, parse-platform

There is a mechanism in node to get the remote IP by calling `req.connection.remoteAddress`.

I tried the below code to get the remote IP of the client but the result is `undefined`.

```
var ipAddr = req.headers["x-forwarded-for"];
if (ipAddr){
    var list = ipAddr.split(",");
    ipAddr = list[list.length-1];
} else {
    ipAddr = req.connection.remoteAddress;
}
console.log("req.connection.remoteAddress:" + ipAddr);
```

Does anyone know if I can get the remoteIP in `Parse.com` cloud code?